# Domain redirection using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wonder how to redirect links with .htaccess.

One domain links `http://domain.com` to index.html, and another `http://www.domain.com` to /wp/index.php.

When someone types `www.my-domain.com` in the browser. I want that domain with www. to redirect to one one file, for example /unique/one.php. And when someone types `my-domain.com` *without* www., that should redirect to another file in my directory, for instance /another/index.php.

Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and provide some examples.

Comment: When someone try to type http://www.my-domain.com/ in browser. I want that domain with www. rediret to one one file for example /unique/one.php And when someone type http://my-domain.com/ without www. that redirect to another file to my directory for instance /another/index.php. Is it now clear?

Comment: Do you want redirect (change URL in browser) or silent rewrite?

Comment: Silent rewrite i think. But really i dont understand what you mean? I want to do it in .htacces

Comment: Redirect means URL changes in browser but silent rewrite means URL stays same.

Comment: I want to do it in silent rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /wp/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.html [L]
```